# How do I prevent black boxed scripts from showing when stepping through Javascript AngularJS code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

I've black-boxed Angular JS scripts, but when I break on mouse click I have to step through VMXXXXXX scripts hundreds of times. I usually give up. Why won't Google Chrome Developer Tools properly skip past this function?

Comment: I think. This function is generated by eval and on every next evaluation get new VMxxxxx link. We're working on blackboxing by content for anonymous scripts. It'll solve the problem. Link to related issue: http://crbug.com/341082

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on your own. Check this: [Become more effective when paused at a breakpoint](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#paused-breakpoint)